# Issue with minting from a DApp for Ethereum

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, mint

Getting error when I hit the mint button and the following function get executed:

```
blockchain.smartContract.methods
  .mint(blockchain.account, mintAmount)
  .send({
    gasLimit: String(totalGasLimit),
    to: CONFIG.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
    from: blockchain.account,
    value: totalCostWei,
  })
  .once("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    setFeedback("Sorry, something went wrong please try again later.");
    setClaimingNft(false);
  })
  .then((receipt) => {
    console.log(receipt);
    setFeedback(
      `WOW, the ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME} is yours! go visit Opensea.io to view it.`
    );
    setClaimingNft(false);
    dispatch(fetchData(blockchain.account));
  });
```

I'm new and need any assistance!

Error is as follows:
[image]

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Ismael i added the error screen

Comment: Can you also share your smart contract code, particularly the mint function? Looks like you are providing enough input parameters for the mint function in your js code

Comment: @Ismael i was able to resolve it. At first my ABI was missing, which cause the first issue of not having the function available. Now I see that the mint function only has one parameter which i addressed.

Comment: You could add the comment as the answer so the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue.

At first my ABI was missing, which cause the first issue of not having the function available.

Once I added the proper ABI info the error message above was thrown.

To fix the issue above I was able to go to my .sol smart contract and see that  my mint function only has one parameter while i was trying to pass two parameters on the site.

Once I removed the second parameter it was resolved and minting worked as desired.

Comment: im sorry can you explain in more detail how there was a second parameter in dapp but not in contract? from @stop-trippin